# kinect image to depth

Tags: c#, opencv, kinect

I am using kinect with opencv.
I want to perform some image operations using opencv on kinect rgb image.
When I get coordinates of a  pixel in rgb and try to map it to depth image using `depthPixel[]`, I get different values of even X and Y coords.

To get value from depthPixels I use something like
`dp[x+y*640].x`

I know method is fine since I get very close values. For (234,355),I get
(223,337,1654).

However I need more accurate values.
How would I acquire this?

Comment: I'm not quite sure whether I understand the problem, but here might be a hint: To map a coordinate from the depth image to the rgb image (and vice-versa), you need the calibration information between both cameras. So if you access the rgb value of `(x,y)` it corresponds to the depth value at another coordinate `(x*,y*)`. So maybe the pixel value at (234,355) in one of the images corresponds to the the pixel value at (223,337) in the other image?!?
This homepage gives some information about kinect stereo calibration!
http://nicolas.burrus.name/index.php/Research/KinectCalibration

Comment: How do you get the coordinates of the pixels in the RGB image?

Comment: Please elaborate what you are trying to do. It is very difficult to understand the problem from this. If you can include some code, that would definitely help us understand and solve the issue.